# set Domain on cookie using spring security when login success

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, redis, spring-session

How can I set the property "domain" on the users cookie when the user has authenticated from spring?

Edit: id like to add domain=".mydomain.com" to cookie with id JSESSIONID

I dont want to deal with spring-session-core or the particular implementation of the session like redis, and Im not using spring-boot. What is the easiest way to do this?

I dont want to jump in the rabbit hole of redis if I can avoid it.

Edit: investigated if set_cookie can be modified in custom implementation of AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl that extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler, but "set_cookie" isnt set until

```
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

of DefaultRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy, but the also isCommitted()==True so set_cookie cant be changed.

I varified this by implementing my redirect strategy:

```
    @Override
public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, java.lang.String url)
        throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("sendRedirect cookie size: "+response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE).size()+ " is commited:"+response.isCommitted());
    String redirectUrl = calculateRedirectUrl(request.getContextPath(), url);
    redirectUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectUrl);
    LOGGER.info("sendRedirect cookie size: "+response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE).size()+ " is commited:"+response.isCommitted());

    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Looks like set_cookie is set in response.sendRedirect and is committed at the same time.

Comment: never done this but you could try using https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html#sessionAuthenticationStrategy(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy) and extend `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy` and add on custom logic

Comment: front-end and backend are running on 2 different servers. So 2 different subdomains but same domain.

Comment: @EndreMoen So you don't want to share the session cookie, you want to share a custom cookie, right?

Comment: i'd like to add attribute domain=".mydomain.com" on cookie with name JSESSIONID